# HashCode implementation for coordinates

Tags: java, hashcode, coordinate

To put you in context: I have a coordinate class where I have two attributes: x and y and those represent pixels. I have redefined the equals method and in it I have given a tolerance of C pixels to determine if two coordinates are equal.

I also tried to redefine the hashCode method because I need to put those coordinates as a key for a map. Here's my redefinition:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 67 * hash + this.x;
    hash = 67 * hash + this.y;
    return hash;
}
```

Now what I want to do is to create a Coordinate whenever a click occurs and get() that coordinate from my map even if it is up to C pixels from the other coordinate. I think my problem is that since it is not the same x and y, they dont have the same hashcode so get() only works if the click occurs exactly at the same x and y. Is there a way to implement my hashcode so that it has a "tolerance" like my equals() does? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You might want to use a `TreeMap` to find nearby values. Though I'm not sure how that would work out with 2-dimensional coordinates.

Comment: My question might not be super clear. What I do when I click is that I create a coordinate on the fly, and then I want get any coordinate that is within C pixels in my map with only the method get() (as it is faster to search, instead of iterating through the entire container...) What I am asking might be impossible though. I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, I understood the question. And anything is possible :)

Comment: Trying to implement fuzzy equality is a bad idea. It's likely to violate some requirements of the [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) contract, specifically transitivity. The simplest solution is probably to scale down your coordinates and use that as a key. E.g., `Coordinates key = new Coordinates(coords.x / C, coords.y / C);`.

Comment: This actually sounds like a really smart idea! I might give that road a go. And my equals() method was definitely violating the transitive part of the contract, didn't notice thanks for the heads up.